# tf.keras.metrics.TruePositives() returning wrong value in model.fit() when passed as metric to model.compile()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

When I pass one-hot encoded labels as train and validation data into tensorflow keras' `model.fit()` function, the metric `tf.keras.metrics.TruePositives()` returns wrong values.

I'm running Tensorflow 2.0.

For example, if this is my code:

```
model.compile(optimizer, 'binary_crossentropy', 
              ['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.TruePositives()])

history = model.fit(train_data, train_labels_binary, batch_size=32, epochs=30,
                    validation_data=(val_data, val_labels_binary), 
                    callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

`train_labels_binary` is this: `array([[1, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1]])`

and the resulting `y_pred`'s are `array([[1, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1]])`

then `tf.keras.metrics.TruePositives()` should return 1, but it returns 3.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I did some more experimenting and it is fixed when the input is not 1-hot encoded and there is only 1 output neuron. So all metrics run correctly if we change the following 2 lines:

This: `train_labels = np.eye(2)[np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(10, 1)).reshape(-1)]`

To: `train_labels = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(10, 1))`

and

This: `model.add(layers.Dense(units=2, activation='sigmoid'))`

To: `model.add(layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))`